# PHP Zip a file via shell_exec and define encryption level

Tags: php, encryption, yii, shell-exec

i'm wondering if anyone can help, I have the following code that zip's a file and password protects - but I want to define the encryption level of the zip, similar to ZipArchive::setEncryptionName, does anyone know if this can be done?

```
$command = "cd $location ; zip ";
$command .= "-P $password ";
$command .= "$filename.zip $filename.csv";
$system = shell_exec($command);
//Set headers
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.zip"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($location . $filename . ".zip"));
readfile($location . $filename . '.zip'); // output the zip
unlink($location . $filename . '.csv'); // delete CSV
unlink($location . $filename . '.zip'); // delete the zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Gsusonline,

For AES-256 encryption, try the following--

```
exec("7z a -p $PASSWORD -mem=AES256 -tzip $ZIP $SOURCE");
```

Additionally, check out CkZip @ https://www.chilkatsoft.com/

As, per their doc found @ https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/phpCkZipRef.html it also has option to use Blowfish and Twofish:

```
int get_EncryptKeyLength() 
void put_EncryptKeyLength(int intVal);
```

> The encryption key length if AES, Blowfish, Twofish, or WinZip-compatible AES encryption is used. This value must be 128, 192, or 256. The default value is 128.

Best,

-Rush

Comment: Thanks Rush, will need to see if i can get this implemented and probably need 7z installed on the server. Don't suppose you would know how to test this to see if it has encrypted to that level do you?